Is a direct airside transit visa needed for UK
My client arrived in the USA on 30 Mar 2024 via London. His return flight on BA departs on 30 Nov 2024
He is travelling on a South African passport with a H2A visa valid until 30 Nov 2024. He will be in transit in London Heathrow the following morning, 01 Dec from 09:30 until 21:00 the same day then fly onwards to South Africa.
The entire journey is booked on one ticket. Will he need a DATV?

Change the flight to depart 29th Nov.
